# react-router four won't let me redirect back to home?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

I have something like this using react-router 4:

```
    <Route exact path="/" children={({match}) => (
      <TransitionGroup component={firstChild}>
        {match && <Home match={match} />}
      </TransitionGroup>
    )}/>
    <Route exact path="/idea/:id" children={({match}) => (
      <TransitionGroup component={firstChild}>
        {match && <IdeaDetails match={match} />}
      </TransitionGroup>
    )}/>
    <Redirect from='*' to='/' />
```

Basically if someone types in a url other than `idea/:id`, I want to redirect them back to the home page.   When I run this code, it seems to do I expect.  Except in the developer consoles, I see this warning

> Warning: You tried to redirect to the same route you're currently on:
>   "/"

Is there a way to define the routes that I have without tripping this warning?   Is there a way to tell react router to not process any subsequent route rules once one of them has been found?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to tell react router to not process any subsequent route rules once one of them has been found?

Yes, you need to wrap your routes in a [`Switch` component](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Switch). When your routes are wrapped in a `Switch`, it finds the FIRST matching route and then returns it without continuing. Without a `Switch`, the router will return ALL routes that match the current url.